# Synchronously scroll two components at once

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an app where a timetable is displayed.

When the right `ScrollView` containing the schedule is scrolled, I want the left `ScrollView` containing the times to scroll too.

```
<ScrollView
    ref={'leftScroll'} />

<ScrollView
    ref={'rightScroll'}
    scrollEventThrottle={1}
    onScroll={(e) => this.refs.leftScroll.scrollTo({y: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)}
    onMomentumScroll={(e) => this.refs.leftScroll.scrollTo({y: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)} />
```

We've managed to scroll it in this way, but it is slow and choppy.
Is there a way to completely synchronize the scroll of these two `ScrollView`s?

The reason for this design is that the times need to be fixed to the left of the screen at all times, and the rooms need to be fixed at the top at all times, and these need to scroll in accordance to the scrolling in the schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's quite difficult due to the way React Native works currently.

Your first `ScrollView` receives the scroll event on the main thread and is scrolled accordingly. Then React Native takes the event and send it to JS thread so it can be handled on the JS side and your `onScroll` event can fire.
Then your handler calls the method to scroll your second `ScrollView`, which means a new event is scheduled from the JS thread to be run on the main thread so the programmatic scroll can happen.

Hence because of all this scheduling and message passing between those threads your second ScrollView will always be a bit behind as you experienced.

So if you really want to have them in sync you'll have to resort to a native implementation (which means 1 implementation for iOS and another implementation for Android).

One possible way is as follows (detailed for iOS):

- write a [custom native module](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) that would have a method which would receive the 2 `reactTag` (using `React.findNodeHandle(component)`) of the `ScrollView` you want to stay in sync
- on the native side in your custom module you'll be able to get a pointer to both `ScrollView` using something like `UIScrollView *scrollView = [[[self bridge] uiManager] viewForReactTag:reactTag]`
- then comes the interesting part where you have to hook into the didScroll event from those `UIScrollView` so that you can add your custom logic to keep them in sync. You could swizzle or replace the `UIScrollView.delegate` (without forgetting to forward the original events to the original delegate). I advise you to have an extensive look at [`RCTScrollView`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6cd712713b1673f13510bc127ac970648f9b5eb3/React/Views/RCTScrollView.m) to find the best place to do that.

I hope you get the idea ;) This is absolutely not trivial to do and you need to have a good deal of experience in iOS programming. But it's a great opportunity to learn new things.

Comment: Thanks for the very concise explanation. I used to be an iOS dev, but making the app "hybrid" myself was something wanted to avoid, but seems this is one to take a leap for.

Answer (score 11):

I have a similar requirement like you describe - ScrollView with times on left and ScrollView with some information on right.

I was able to get the smooth scrolling to work in react-native with a small change to your code above (though I am not using onMomentumScroll). In the docs they mention an animated attribute on the scrollTo method: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto

```
onScroll={(e) => this.refs.timeScroll.scrollTo({y: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y, animated: false})}
```

Important to note that `scrollEventThrottle={16}` is required to otherwise the scrolling again is choppy. React-Native docs mention that values 1-16 are not noticeable - and so to use 16.

Edit:

I thought i'd come and give an update to this. My above solution worked to an extent, however it still has the smallest delay that ends up being noticeable.

In the end I ended up implementing Animated as it uses native only.

Define:

```
const yOffset = new Animated.Value(0);
const onScroll = Animated.event(
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: yOffset } } }],
  { useNativeDriver: true }
);
```

Create Method:

```
viewTranslate() {
    return {
      transform: [{
        translateY: yOffset.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0,1],
          outputRange: [1,0]
        })
      }]
    };
  }
```

Assign style to Animated.View:

```
<Animated.View style={this.viewTranslate()>...</Animated.View>
```

Assign event to Animated.ScrollView:

```
<Animated.ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={1} onScroll={onScroll}>...</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Comment: I know this is late but thank you, just what i'm looking for. Been stucking on this problem for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the Animated solution proposed by @adam_, but I found the view translation itself allows for no clipping so ultimately it was not suitable for a table with a fixed header and left column.  The animation would run over those.

Also, when used with a flat list, it does not load columns as it scrolls because it is a pure view translation, so empty space scrolls onto the screen.

If anyone has any clues for this, appreciated.